# c - output is not changing after being put through a function

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

This is an extension of a homework question I submitted last night. The program got too messy for me so I took a step back and am starting over with some new knowledge of returns and pass bys. The entire program is meant to take any number of integers, and first find the sum and average, then print the square root of each integer, then print a boolean true or false if any integer is less than 20 and finally print a boolean true or false if any integer is between 10 and 90.

But right now all I need to do is to get my head wrapped around this. Currently I am only going to tackle the sum and average portion of this. It must be done using pass by references which, to my knowledge, is what I have been using in the code shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int functionSumAvg(int sumAvgInput);

void main()
{
  int amountOfNumbers,number,x,output;

  output = 0;

  printf("Enter how many numbers you want: ");
  scanf("%d",&amountOfNumbers);
  printf("Input each number, separated by a space: ");

  for(x = 0; x < amountOfNumbers; ++x){
    scanf("%d",&number);
    int output = functionSumAvg(number);

  }
  printf("output: %d",output);
}


int functionSumAvg(int sumAvgInput){
  int sum =+ sumAvgInput;
  return sum;
}
```

The idea that I was getting is that you put in the amount of integers you want, then it goes through summing one, adding that sum to the output, and repeating until it's all done. Afterwards it would print out the final output, the result of all the integers summed up. But instead it prints zero. Originally it printed out what I assumed was the memory address, some big trash number, so I set it to zero. But that was only a band aid solution, and didn't solve the problem itself.

Comment: `int sum =+ sumAvgInput;` What do you think this does?

Comment: Adds sum and sumAvgInput and sets whatever the result is to sum

Comment: ... and which book are you reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fuctionSumAvg` doesn't compute the sum or average of anything. It just sets the local variable `sum` to the number that it received, and returns that same number. It's not adding it to a previous total. And calculating an average requires dividing the sum by the count of elements, but you never sum or count anything.

You can use static variables to hold the running sum and count. But since a function can only return one value, you'll need to use a pointer parameter to return a second value.

```
int functionSumAvg(int sumAvgInput, int *avg){ // return value is sum
  static int sum = 0;
  static int count = 0;
  sum += sumAvgInput;
  count++;
  *avg = sum/count;
  return sum;
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
int sum, average;
sum = functionSumAvg(number, &average);
printf("Sum = %d Average = %d\n", sum, average);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int output = functionSumAvg(number);
```

creates a new temporary `output`

do

```
 output = functionSumAvg(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, is that you are not passing by reference. You are passing by value.

You need to pass-in a reference (a pointer in C) to the sum, and pass-in (by value) the new value to be added to the sum. The calling routine would then be responsible for initialising the sum to zero.

```
int functionSumAvg(int *sum_pt, int input){…}
```

I won't tell you the rest, because it will get in the way of your learning.

Note: I use a `_pt` post-fix for my pointers, I don't use any other Hungarian notation.

Comment: Pass-by-reference and reference values themselves are distinct topic, let alone pointers, albeit all overlapping in definition, and can be used in a turing machine to mimic the same feature (which is essentially a maybe monad). C doesn't have pass-by-reference, though it does have pointers which you could say are a kind of reference type. To be clear, in C, you are _always_ passing by value. You might be passing a reference type by value, but that's still passing by value. The distinction is in `swap(x, y);` (the same reason `scanf` needs ampersands)... try that in C ;)

Comment: Oh, and I think while we're talking about learning, this question wasn't born from someone who's reading a book... right? I mean, that's just a guess. I mean, I've never seen books teach this `int sum =+ ...` stuff... I think he/she is just guessing, treating the language like a black box and learning by observation (which is unsafe), so the best we can do for his/her learning is get him/her reading a good book... having said that, he/she would be reading one now instead of asking questions, right? Will he/she even read this answer?

Comment: @Autistic do you recommend any good books. And what is the difference between `swap(ref x, ref y);` and `swap(&x, &y)`? ( All pass by reference implementations in all languages, pass references by value)

Comment: Nah I totally don’t look at the comments

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor [C11/6.5.2.2p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2) states "In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument". This description corresponds precisely to the definition of "pass by value". C is thus always passing by value.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor See also [this blog post](http://www.javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) for the differences between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, more specifically the swap test I was referring to.

Comment: As for book recommendations, if you're new to programming, you'll probably find [SICP](http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf) enlightening, because even though it teaches you how to program using a relatively obscure programming language, more importantly it will teach you how to utilise common methods of abstraction. Only once you're familiar with procedural programming and comfortable reading manual pages should you learn C; it's subtly dangerous any other way. With that prerequisite in mind, K&R2E has been successful for myself and thousands of others...

Comment: @DFT95 Congrats for making it this far. See my prior comment for a book recommendation, if needed. K&R2E is under 300 pages long, and will answer this question as well as the thousands of other common questions you're bound to waste tonnes of time debugging and asking (which we'll then need to reinvent the K&R2E wheel to answer)... if you're a fast learner and a fast reader, you could learn C in a month. Try treating C as a black box, however, and in ten years time you'll be shocked to learn you don't know C. I've been there, done that, got the tee. Do you want to repeat my footsteps?